# Cambiar idioma de los textos de input date a español

Tags: html, c#, mvc, date, input

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion MVC C# y en un formulario tengo un par de inputs type="date" el problema es que los textos estan en ingles y necesito que esten en español, intente agregarle el atributo lang="es" pero no funciona.

Los inputs los estoy escribiendo de la siguiente forma:

```
   <input type="date" id="dateFrom" name="DateFrom" asp-for="@Model.DateFrom" class="form-control" />
                          <input type="date" id="dateTo" name="DateTo" asp-for="@Model.DateTo" class="form-control" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En que idioma tienes el navegador?

Comment: En ingles, voy a intentar cambiarlo, de todas formas no se podria forzar el idioma del input?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186908/how-to-change-input-type-date-calender-language-localization